# $\frac{A}{B}$ for $A=\frac1{1\cdot2}+\frac1{3\cdot4}+\dots+\frac1{21\cdot22}$ and $B=\frac1{12\cdot22}+\frac1{13\cdot21}+\dots+\frac1{22\cdot12}$

Tags: summation, divisibility

Problem :

Let :

$A=\dfrac{1}{1\cdot2}+\dfrac{1}{3\cdot4}+...+\dfrac{1}{21\cdot22}$

And

$B=\dfrac{1}{12\cdot22}+\dfrac{1}{13\cdot21}+...+\dfrac{1}{22\cdot12}$

Then find the value of : $\dfrac{A}{B}$

My try :

$A=\sum_{n=1}^{11}\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)(2n)}$

Wolfram alpha give me 
$A=\dfrac{156188887}{2327925960}$

But about B I'm not sure .

$B=\sum_{n=0}^{10}\dfrac{1}{(12+n)(22-n)}=\dfrac{47497}{554400}$

But I don't know how I calculated the summation in fast way ? 
And I'm searching a simple method

Comment: I don't see $13.21$ in your summation formula for $B$

Comment: For $A$ , Wolfram Alpha gives the following partial sum : $$\dfrac12 \left( \psi ^{(0)} \left( m+\dfrac 12 \right)  - \psi ^{(0)}(m+1) - \gamma -  \psi ^{(0)} \left( \dfrac 12 \right) \right)$$

Comment: Ellen could you give some context on why you want to compute this?

Comment: The formula has been corrected but the numerical value for B is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using partial fractions decompositions
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}&=\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\\
\frac{1}{(11+n)(23-n)}&=\frac{1}{34}\left(\frac{1}{11+n}+\frac{1}{23-n}\right)
\end{align}
we have
\begin{align}
A&=\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\dots+\left(\frac{1}{21}-\frac{1}{22}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{21}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac{1}{22}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{22}\right)-2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac{1}{22}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{22}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{11}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{13}+\dots+\frac{1}{22}\right)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
34\cdot B&=\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{22}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{21}\right)+\dots+\left(\frac{1}{22}+\frac{1}{12}\right)\\
&=2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{13}+\dots+\frac{1}{22}\right)\\
&=2\cdot A
\end{align}
so $A/B=17$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps but python gives $\frac{A}{B} = 17$

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction as f
>>> A = sum(f(1, i * (i + 1)) for i in range(1, 22, 2))
>>> B = sum(f(1, i * (34 - i)) for i in range(12, 23))
>>> A / B
Fraction(17, 1)
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I want to post the code because it is short enough and everybody can try it. I don't think it is so irrelevant as it is currently the only place on this thread where the value $\frac{A}{B} = 17$ appears.

Comment: Sorry again for my testiness - it was because of the damaging edit to my answer, not because of your comment/answer, which is indeed helpful. If I hadn't been thrown off balance by the things that had gone wrong with my answer (a technical bug - on top of another bug that has been driving me mad for days - followed by an edit that didn't help), I would have acknowledged the usefulness of the comment, before pointing out that it is not an answer - which of course it *is*, in a sense!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> Express $A$ and $B$ in terms of the harmonic numbers: $$H_n = \frac11 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \cdots + \frac1n \quad (n \geqslant 1).$$

It might also help - but this is such a weak hint, there is no need to hide it! - to consider the more general problem of computing a simple form for $\frac{A}{B},$ where for some positive integer $m:$
\begin{gather*}
A = \sum_{r=1}^m\frac1{(2r - 1)(2r)}, \\
B = \sum_{r=1}^m\frac1{(m + r)(2m - r + 1)}.
\end{gather*}

Comment: I can't tell if the spoiler mechanism (see [Markdown Editing Help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help)) is working or not. (My old browser isn't supported by SE any more.) If I have simply made some mistake in using it, could someone please edit my post? It *seemed* to work in preview mode. (I tried several variants, and posted the one that worked. The behaviour of the previewer was inconsistent - which is not unusual.)

Comment: @Gribouillis [Damn, even the "@" mechanism is no longer working for me, with this browser!]: Did you even read my comment? If you don't know how to hide a spoiler, you shouldn't have edited the answer. It's now worse, not better. I had already flagged it for moderator attention. I'd better leave it for them to sort out, rather than reversing your edit.

Comment: There are several threads in Meta about the [spoiler](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=spoiler) problem, which seems to be a long-standing one. I haven't time to read any of those threads in full now, but I've used the advice in one of the answers to do a quick fix - I hope!

Comment: Sorry I guess I misunderstood your request to edit the post. That said, why don't you want the hint to appear?

Comment: @Gribouillis [Ah, the "@" worked that time!] Sorry I was a bit testy. (By the way, your comment/answer is helpful - but not an answer, unless the OP desperately wants to know the value of $\frac{A}{B}$ in this case, but no other similar case! In answer to your question: as is apparent, I don't often use the spoiler mechanism! (I can't recall ever using it, but I probably have, in a bug-free case.) But when reading a problem or puzzle in a book, I like to know if a hint is available, without always wanting to know what it is. It seemed reasonable to give the OP or other reader the same choice.

Comment: I have reached a philosophical position where I consider that an answer like the one I gave here is a very convincing mathematical proof. Think about it, we're entering a new era.

Comment: @Gribouillis Oh, I *love* pottering about with Python, numpy, matplotlib, SciPy, and so on. As a result, I have become *fully* persuaded of the truth of quite a few mathematical "facts" that I don't remotely know how to prove, or in some cases even to formulate. (Don't get me started! I'm tempted to give examples, but the system would then create links to unconnected questions.) Still, one should not blur the distinction between such quasi-empirical evidence (however compelling, even to me) and proof. (Sometimes it does get frustrating that MSE is not a discussion forum, doesn't it?)

Comment: I agree that this is not the place to discuss this, but it is a fascinating subject. Note that in this case we are talking about exact calculation with small integers. It is not only empirical evidence. The proof lies in the expression of the algorithm.

Comment: I daren't carry on this "chat" much further, but I've added something to my answer that might help to make my point. (If not, never mind! It's such a large topic that it's bound to be possible to find discussions of it elsewhere, and maybe even take part in such discussions - although I personally don't yet feel ready to formulate a definite position, even provisionally.)

Comment: @Gribouillis You might be amused by the entry for Dec 11 in my profile. :)

Comment: I don't know where to look.

Comment: (I don't want the system to create a link to an unrelated question.) Click my name, click the "Profile" tab, scroll down to the entry for Dec 11 in "Newest posts", and look at the very end of the answer. You'll probably feel that the bit at the end was all that was needed. :)

Comment: I certainly do.